# Testing for Pixel Agreement in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, con

Say I have 2 rasters with same spatial extent and same resolution and same number of classes:

Raster 1: Ground Truth.

Raster 2: Result of some algorithm.

I want to see what % of pixels have same value. To achieve this I tried following in raster calculator

```
outras = Con("ras1.tif" = "ras2.tif", 1,0)
```

I am getting error:

> Runtime error SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: How about subtracting one from the other and then check the histogram for the frequency of 0 value?

Comment: Replace = by ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Replace = by == – FelixIP

^ This works